# EditText focus problem

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edit text which is placed as the first widget in my screen. So every time the page load the cursor stands inside this edit text, which I don't require. How can I remove focus from this when the page gets loaded? I tried with `edittext.clearFocus()`, but it didn't work out. Can anyone please reply me a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

This can be used to suppress the keyboard until the user actually touched the edittext view.

From [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard/1109108#1109108):

> You can force Android to hide the virtual keyboard using the
>   InputMethodManager, calling hideSoftInputFromWindow, passing in the
>   token of the window containing your edit field.
>
> ```
> InputMethodManager imm =
>     (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
> imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
> ```
>
> This will force the keyboard to be hidden in all situations. In some
>   cases you will want to pass in InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY
>   as the second parameter to ensure you only hide the keyboard when the
>   user didn't explicitly force it to appear (by holding down menu).

Answer (score 0):

You can have request focus in any other field, or this should not be the first field.